# How to pass table name a parameter in Azure data factory

Tags: database, azure, updates, data-warehouse, azure-data-factory

I'm a new user in the Azure data factory. I tried to perform copy activity in between Azure database as the source and Azure data warehouse as a target . In that, I am not able to perform an update into target using data factory.  In which Source as Azure SQL server and target as the Azure data warehouse.  And how to update the field in data warehouse table in Azure using ADF when the data warehouse is a sink

Comment: Hello and welcome! What have you already done? Usually, when using data factory to move data, you would like to have a stored procedure to do the data transformation for you. The procedure could use a merge operation to insert/update/delete the data. Usually, on the sink side, you chose a table and a stored procedure that relates to that data, with a table type that represents it. Can  you provide more information on what you've done?

Comment: I have few table in my source database , which is azure SQL database i need to copy this data to my azure  SQL data warehouse .I tried to do this activity with the reference of  this link .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal. Here the sink is SQL data base. Insted of SQL data base i use data warehouse in my senario. But in data warehouse I am not able to create type .Says it is no allowed to create type.So I need an alternative way to do this activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your pasted link I assume what expected is incrementally copy data from Azure sql database to Azure data warehouse.

In this case no need to modify the sink database, instead finish the modification before loading into sink table.

I followed the steps in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal), in which the target is: Azure Blob storage, I changed it to: Azure data warehouse. And the test result is successfully implemented data copying from Azure database to Azure data warehouse incrementally.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, Actually i don't have permission to modify source data base I got only read permission .In SQL data warehouse Table type is not support.so I am not able to pass table name if i want run same pipe for multiple table.So i just want to know is their any alternative way to pass table name to stored procedure without creating type